# New Thread For New Form

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, winforms

Requirement : I Want To make a Button That Performs Following Actions .

1) Creates New Form .
2) That New Form Should Have Progress Bar In it At Any location.
3) on each Click That New Form Shows Progress Bar Processing From Start.

Please help me Out I am Stuck at this Point .. I have been trying But Unable To Find The Way For Out...

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Download d = new Download();
            d.progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
            d.progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            d.Show();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
                d.progressBar1.Value = I;
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); thread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Post code for what you have tried so far..

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
             {
                 Download d = new Download();
                 d.progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
                 d.progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
                 d.Show();
                 for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
                     d.progressBar1.Value = I;
             });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }

Comment: Dont Know Why There IS No New line Comming...  This is First time I Am Posting Any Question At this Platform

Comment: Do not post code in comments, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29544114/edit), add the code, then delete the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code will work they you wanted. You need to update the progress bar from a different.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Download d = new Download();
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {               
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(30);
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
                {
                    d.progressBar1.Value = i;
                }));  
            }               
        });            
        d.progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
        d.progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        d.Show(); 
    }
```

Comment: When Clicking On Button It Is Giving The Following error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: i Am Really Thank Full of u That U Are Responding Me  ... And I Want To Tell u that Why I need This Type Of requirement ... Actually i am Doing Socket programming on C# And currently i am Working on the Project in which i am Supposed To send And Receive Multiple Files At A Time in Different threads ... i am Done With Single File At A Time Doesn't Matter How Big File It Is  ... now i Am Stuck At this Stage When i Want To Receive Multiple Files And Each File's Information and Progress Is Show in New Form ... So i Thought First i Should Do That Without Sockets Programming